# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values' Centos7 Python

Tags: python, json, centos

I have a mistake that I can't solve.. have you got an advice?

```
[root@leemi wwwroot]# python3 DateRead.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DateRead.py", line 33, in <module>
    data_ls = json.load(data_file)["Person"].values()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Code created in VS.

```
import os
import datetime
import psycopg2
import inspect
import json
import io
from collections import OrderedDict

mtime = os.path.getmtime("data.json")
with io.open("saveDate.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as date_read:
    ttime = date_read.read()

if str(mtime) == ttime:
    with io.open('data.json', "r", encoding="utf-8") as data_file:    
        data_ls = json.load(data_file)["Person"].values()
    # datas1 = OrderedDict(sorted(data_ls["Person"].itemsc(), key=lambda t: t[0]))3
    # print(datas1)
    datas = list(data_ls)
    # datas2 = [str(datas["PersonSex"]), str(datas["PersonAge"]), str(datas["PersonDate"])]
    print(datas[0],datas[1],datas[2])

    with io.open("saveDate.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as date_save:
        date_save.write("{0}".format(mtime))
    print("INSERT INTO public.\"DbPerson\"(\"PersonSex\", \"PersonAge\", \"PersonDate\") VALUES ('{0}',{1},'{2}');".format(datas[0], datas[1], datas[2]))
```

VS has no errors. However, an error occurs at run time in Centos 7. As I'm a beginner of Python, I've searched for many things, but I can't solve them. Please help me.

Result

```
F 40 2020-05-01 8:10:00
INSERT INTO public."DbPerson"("PersonSex", "PersonAge", "PersonDate") VALUES ('F',40,'2020-05-01 8:10:00');
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `json.load(data_file)["Person"]` is already a list. And in Python list types don't have any `values()` method. This is essentially what the error message is telling you. VS has no idea about the data structure so it cannot catch this error.

Try changing line 33 to:

```
data_ls = json.load(data_file)["Person"]
```

Comment: print("INSERT INTO public.\"DbPerson\"(\"PersonSex\", \"PersonAge\", \"PersonDate\") VALUES ('{0}',{1},'{2}');".format(datas[0], datas[1], datas[2]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Failed to get data from values() in Json file.

Comment: What does your JSON file look like?